# What is the meaning of "local" in the sentence, "Local wolf girl goes Awoo"?

Tags: meaning, pun

I saw an image that I'm going to ask on some humor posting page, like below:

[image: awoo]

I searched the meaning of sentence "Local wolf girl goes Awoo", and found that "go" is meaning "bark" when using with describing sound words, like "Awoo".

However, I still have a question about the "Local" in the sentence. I know that "Local" is meaning "province", pointing a near area where one exists or restricted section which is separated from global. I think these meanings are irrelevant. Do you know what is the meaning of the "Local" in the sentence?

Comment: Google **[Go AWOL](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-awol)** or just **[AWOL](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/AWOL)**. The joke is that "goes awoo" (starts barking) sounds similar to "goes AWOL" (goes "absent-without-leave").

Comment: You might have gotten *local* mixed up with *locale*. A *locale* is an area of unspecified size - it's a noun. *Local* is an adjective and as the answers have said, means "in or from the immediate area".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Newspapers other than national ones often run stories which emphasize the origins of someone prominent, using a headline similar in construction to this.

For example the home-town paper of an astronaut may run a story with a headline such as "Local Man Reaches for the Stars"

Your example is simply using this idiom.

Answer (score 7):

"Goes" is a common English idiom for "says". For example:

> He asked me where Fred is so I go, "He's not here."

"Local" means "from this place". For example, here in Monroe Michigan we might say, "General Custer is a local hero", because he is a famous person who lived in our town. Or if you say, "I am dating a local girl", you mean a girl who lives nearby, as opposed to a girl from far away.

Without reading the article I have no idea what a "wolf girl" might be, but you didn't seem puzzled about that part.

@copperkettle may be right that it's a pun on "goes AWOL", though that means something completely different. In that case "go" means to physically move, and "AWOL" is a military abbreviation for "Away Without Official Leave". So to "go AWOL" is referring to a soldier who leaves the base or wherever he's supposed to be without proper permission.

Comment: "you mean a girl who lives nearby, as opposed to a girl from far away." Or a girl who has always (or at least for a significant part of their childhood) lived nearby, as opposed to a girl who has moved here from far away. My general understanding when somebody uses "local" to refer to a person, is that they're "from here" in the sense that they were born and/or raised here, not just that they currently live here. That does tie a lot more closely to your General Custer example as a "local hero".

Comment: Born/raised is the better interpretation, though it requires the context of the speaker being somebody who *does* live in the area where the subject was born/raised. The phrase "local girl made good" would refer to somebody local-to-the-speaker who has done well for themselves. The girl in question could live or work someplace else, like a major city or center of a particular industry, and done well there.

Comment: Hmm, I think what makes someone "local" is not rigidly defined. The archtypical newspaper story, "Local boy makes good" often means someone who was born or spent his childhood here, and who may or may not be living here now. If he moved to the big city where he became rich and famous, he could have moved away years ago and we'd still call him "local". But if a company said, "We want to hire a local person for this job", they probably mean someone who is presently living nearby, regardless of where he was born, and the issue is that they don't want to have to pay travel costs for people to ...

Comment: ... come for interviews or have to put up with the extra time for such travel, or pay relocation expenses for the person they hire. If your mother said, "You should marry a local girl and not one of those city-slickers who are taking over our town", she clearly means someone who was born or raised in the area. But "You should marry a local girl rather than using that international dating agency" probably means someone who lives here now, regardless of where she was born. Etc.

Comment: @CopperKettle Touhou is not an anime. Nor is it "furry" (most of the characters are based on some kind of mythological creature, the particular character pictured is a Tengu.)

Comment: @Random832 - thanks, mate! I scraped my comment. I'm out to lunch in this field. (0: